# Join two tables with a reference table

Tags: sql

I have two tables and a third to link the records. I am trying to make a query that will select t1.name and t2.value where their ID's are tied in table 3. It has been so long since I have done any sql I cannot remember how to do this properly,

```
Table1
-------------
ID     Name
1      bill
2      bob
3      ben
4      steve

Table2
ID     Value
--------------
1      blue
2      red
3      green
4      orange

Table3
-----------------------------
ID     Table1ID     Table2ID
1      4            2
2      3            1
3      2            4
4      1            3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple `INNER JOIN`.
Might be quicker to get an answer by searching sql tutorials then by asking here.

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table2.Name
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Id = Table3.Table1Id
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.Table2Id = Table2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should be something like this for example in MySQL dialect.

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Value FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.Table1ID = t1.ID
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t3.Table2ID = t2.ID;
```

However, note that there can be several variants, and the best for you depends on your exact database specification (for example LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN, etc.)

Comment: Actually, this is ANSI SQL, and should work on most databases

Comment: Yes, might be, but AFAIK for example Postgres, Oracle, etc. needs quoting in several cases when one uses case-sensitive names.